# Notation for vector space of linear functions

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

What is the most usual notation for the vector space, over the field $\mathcal{F}$, defined by all linear functions that map $U$ to $V$ ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It varies from book to book, the most common I have seen is $\mathcal{L}(U,V)$.

Comment: ... or sometimes $\operatorname{Hom}(U,V)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above: In Axler's book, the notation is $\mathcal{L}(U,V)$. In books that take a more "modern" approach, you will often find $\text{Hom}_{\mathbf{k}}(U,V)$, where $\mathbf{k}$ denotes the field over which the vector spaces $U,V$ are defined. Or, you may find the simplified notation $\text{Hom}(U,V)$ when the field $\mathbf{k}$ is clear.

The reason for this latter notation is the prevalence of the mention of $\textbf{Vec}_\mathbf{k}$, the category of vector spaces over the field $\mathbf{k}$, with $\mathbf{k}-$linear maps as morphisms. If you aren't familiar, don't worry about the details. I just wanted to add context.